# How to detect User typing in console vs. Background Task using BATCH commands?

Tags: session, batch-file, background, task

I would like to know how to detect whether there is a person behind the computer that's using the Windows Server Terminal/Console to launch a set of BATCH scripts, or whether there is an automates Background Task that's launching those scripts.
I must detect this using simple batch script.

I've been looking around on the internet for possible differences between those 2 types of "users", but I can't find anything helpful. Any solution is welcomed: keystroke capture, redirected Standard Input, Terminal/Console session IDs, etc. I tried all those, but couldn't succeed until now.

The solution has to work on Windows Server 2003, 2008 and 2008 R2.
But for to begin with, I'd be more than happy to see it work on just WS 2003.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I think I don't really understand what you mean with "*how to detect whether there is a person behind the computer*". However, at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2800) there is a way to detect *if STDIN was redirected to a disk file*, that may mean that no person is typing the input to this Batch file, but that is was started in an automated way.  For example:

```
TypeOfHandle 0
if %errorlevel% geq 128 (
    rem STDIN redirected to disk file
    echo This program must be executed in interactive (not predefined-input) way^!
    goto :EOF
)
set /P input=Enter input please: 
etc...
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: +1, But I'm not sure that the input will be redirected, I suppose the batch will simply started by a user or by a sort of automatic like `autostart`

Comment: Btw. You should escape the last bracket in your `echo ... (not predefined-input^) way^!`

Answer (score 0):

```
If /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" pause
```

This is generally true for batch files that are double clicked.

```
@for /f "tokens=10* delims=," %A in ('tasklist /fi "SESSION ne 1" /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /nh /fo CSV') do echo %A
```

Will list cmd title running in other sessions.